# CUPS support for drivers

Tags: konica

First sorry for my bad English.

I don't now is this right place for my question but i want to ask. Can somebody tell me who are develop drivers for koncica minolta bizhub 163 on Ubuntu for cups, and if somebody work on it where can i read the state of driver.

Answer (score -2):

Try with: http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/openprinting-ppds-postscript-konica-minolta_20100531-1lsb3.2_all.deb

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, it just provides the driver, as a package (not even the download page) in an amd64 version only without license, working features, or where to submit bugs.

Comment: OK this is good but when i install package in printer preference don't show new driver to select. May be i doing something wrong.

Comment: If it is already installed then check the version from the `about` section of driver with the downloaded version `20100531-1lsb3.2_all.deb` in this case.

Comment: Driver for this printer doesn’t exist in the list. My question is from where i download this ppd or something else to work with this stupid konica minolta 163.